# git repository location on gitlab server is missing data

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

Gitlab server has a empty repository though i have couple of project pushed onto the gitlab url

I have created a gitlab server, using docker-compose file. The git lab is setup successfully, i logged into the console, created a new group, then new project and then pushed a sample docs into the new repository.

I can see the data from gitlab console at the navigation:

```
http://<URL>:8888/devops-group/maven/tree/master
```

However, when i login to the server and i go to the below path i do not see any data:

```
root@gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories# pwd
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
root@gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories# ls -ltr
total 0
drwxr-s---. 3 git root 16 Aug 15 02:36 @hashed
root@gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories#
```

while creation of gitlab using docker-compose i have used below code

```
  volumes:
   - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
   - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
   - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Whatever the projects or code i have pushed onto the repository, I should be able to see them on the server.
Also i need to create git hooks therefore i need this path location on the gitlab server. Please help me to find the repository location for my projects on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first your `gitlab.rb` configuration file in `/srv/gitlab/config` (on your server).

A [default one would include a storage](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/2bb475adbaf751f6f410fbdcc3c0066082ddd73b/config/gitlab.yml.example#L878-892) set to `/home/git/repositories/`.

If that path does not start with `/srv/gitlab/data`, that would explain why nothing is mapped to `/var/opt/gitlab`.

Check "[Run the image](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#run-the-image)"

The idea behind those volume definitions is to store and persists data on the Docker host. Make sure the folder `/src/gitlab/xxx` exist and are writable.

Comment: i see the gitlab.rb present on the git server at the location /etc/gitlab, however i dont see this path /srv/gitlab/data anywhere inside the file. rather '## Repositories settings' section is missing, Is there a problem with gitlab server container creation, how can i fix this issue to map and mount the repository location.

Comment: @Jagdish0886 `/srv/gitlab/xxx` is a folder on your host. Does it exist?

Comment: yes the path /srv/gitlab/xxx on my host machine does exist and this contains logs config and data directories

Comment: @Jagdish0886 Does your  `gitlab.rb` include the section I mention in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/2bb475adbaf751f6f410fbdcc3c0066082ddd73b/config/gitlab.yml.example#L878-892? You need to define a default storage for those repositories to be created in the expected path.

Comment: thank you for your response...this section does not present, which is mentioned in the url you have referred, i did mention three volumes for log data and config(though these are created but data repositories are missing), while launching the git lab container server, can you please suggest how to create this section exclusively, i was assuming this should create automatically while creation of data (the snippet i mentioned in my very first question).

Comment: @Jagdish0886 Can you search for the complete path of your created repository in your Docker GitLab container? If it starts with `/var/opt/gitlab`, it should be reflected in `/srv/gitlab/data`.

Comment: I could locate repositories path at (/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories) but nothing inside except @hashed directory which has recursive directories inside. But no real physical location of my deployed projects.  Next level of directories are : @hashed/4e/07/4e07408562bedb8b60ce05c1decfe3ad16b72230967de01f640b7e4729b49fce.git/objects, the path goes on and on.

Comment: @Jagdish0886 "nothing inside except @hashed directory": that is expected and normal: `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories` will host **bare**  repositories (Git database only, no actual working tree with their checked out files)

Comment: ok, good to know that setup is as designed, however, could you please clarify, where can i find my checked out directories. I am currently working only on master branch, and while checkout of the code it says 'already on master'. My prime motive is to find checkout code on the server (or inside the repositories) or is there a method/command to see it inside the repositories.

Comment: @Jagdish0886 The GitLab docker image is meant to be a hosting Git repository server. "Hosting" means "bare repositories only. You find checkout code only where you have *cloned* those repositories (on your local workstation, using an URL of your GitLab server)

Comment: ok got it, and yes i have cloned those on my local machine, so i have data i need, but how can i achieve git hooks for particular repositories/projects, this is what i was trying in first place. to create a git hook which i want to trigger those from jenkins when i commit a code to git (server or repo). Please note there is a separate container for gitlab server and jenkins.

Comment: @Jagdish0886 You can add custom servers side hook on GitLab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html

Answer (score 0):

try running this command in your git container. this should resolve your problem.

`gitlab-rake gitlab:storage:rollback_to_legacy ID_FROM=1 ID_TO=50`

Comment: Hi, maybe you could provide an explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered same issue and here is how I figured it out and ran git hook successfully:

---

**Answer to part-I of your query**(Please help me to find the repository location for my projects on the server):

*Gitlab supports following repository storage types-* https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_types.html

From GitLab 10.0 onwards git lab supports hashed storage for repository and in GitLab13.0, legacy repository storage is deprecated.

In hashed storage we can find the location of repository as mentioned in this link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_types.html#from-project-name-to-hashed-path

1. Find Gitaly relative path from gitlab web ui(**Menu >> admin >> Projects >> select/click on your project >> copy the value of "*Gitaly relative path:*"**)

For ex: @hashed/9f/14/9f14025af0065b30e47e23ebb3b491d39ae8ed17d33739e5ff3827ffb3634953.git

This hashed path can also be found using rails console as mentioned in above shared 2nd link.

2. Your Git repository location would be **"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/Gitaly relative path"**

For ex: /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/9f/14/9f14025af0065b30e47e23ebb3b491d39ae8ed17d33739e5ff3827ffb3634953.git

---

**Answer to part-II of your query**(
Also i need to create git hooks therefore i need this path location on the gitlab server):

The dir found in above **step 2** is the git repository directory where you can create **custom_hooks** dir and place your git hooks into it.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html

***Note:*** In order to run the hook successfully, please ensure that you provide proper permission to custom_hook dir/hooks as well as the ownership to the required user.