# Can't find GitLab repositories directory [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: git, file, gitlab, repository

I know repositories are by default stored at /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories and I do remember seeing all of them there.
We're now trying to move our GitLab installation into a new server and went to that directory to fetch everything and I've found it's empty, just the +gitaly and @hashed directories are there.
I also checked the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file to see if it was changed bit it's not.
Any ideas on how to follow? GitLav version is 13.10.0

Edit: I'm not using Docker for GitLab, it's installed using their PPA.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520325/git-repository-location-on-gitlab-server-is-missing-data) ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm not using docker for GitLab, thanks anyway @boolfalse

Answer (score 0):

Well... it seems GitLab forced my installation to go into "hashed storage" and that's why I couldn't find the repositories, becasue they were actually there but with a "hashed" path.